# How can i change the previous fraction value when the fraction value is 5. in c language

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, floating-accuracy

I was trying to write a code where after decimal value if the fraction value is 0.005 then it will print the value as 0.01. I tried to use **%0.02f** but it this method didn't work. my full code is below and the input value.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float a,b,c=0,d=0,e=0;
    while(1)
    {
        a=0;b=0;c=0,d=0,e=0;
    scanf("%f%f",&a,&b);
    c=b-a;
    d=c*100.0;
    e=d/a;
    //printf("%0.2f\n%0.2f\n%0.2f\n",c,d,e);
    printf("%0.2f%%\n",e);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

input `999.95 1000.00`

expected output = `0.01%`

My output = `0.00%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math, with 32 bit `float`s, comes up with a final value for `e` of `0.004999...`, not the "logical" `0.005` you expect (and expect to round to `0.01`). That's [just how it is with floating point math](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/364696). Rounding that to two decimal places accurately describes the result as `0.00`; it's less than `0.005`, so it rounds to `0.00`, not `0.01`.

Using a more precise type (`double`) *might* help (it does on my machine [after changing the `scanf` to use `%lf`], but many compilers, especially with higher optimizations, and some architectures, violate IEEE-754 specs, and might disagree), but fundamentally, floating point math will introduce errors relative to precise logical arithmetic, so you should be using a different approach if you can't tolerate even small errors, e.g. fixed point `int`-based math, or `libmpdec` or the like for full decimal (base-10) floating point math.

Note that depending on what you choose to do, you may need to be careful about the rounding mode; C99 rounds half-way values away from zero, but there are other rounding modes (round half-even being a common one due to not introducing a bias in the rounding) that would produce `0.00` when rounding to two decimal places, even if you *did* produce `0.005` precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten a "0" in your `%0.2` in the code based off of your wording in the question.